# PERL How to call a script inside perl every 5 mins

Tags: perl

Example I have a perl script made then I have this script:

How to call a script inside perl script every 5 mins

---

```
#! /bin/perl
#bla bla bla many scripts written

sub failure {
print "Just a sample print";
}
```

---

I want to call failure every 5 minutes.

I can't find a simple clear answer.

I saw from one of my former team mate, his Perl script executes a script inside perl like this:

```
my $mainWindow -> repeat ( 1000, \&failure );
```

If I try to replicate it, it gives an error saying:

```
can't call method repeat, unidentified value at line 222
```

I have a hard time reverse engineering his script too coz its too complicated for me... I am not use to his scripts... Thanks for the help....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
while (1) {
    failure();
    sleep(5*60);
}
```

Comment: Thanks leeduhem, O_o I just wonder why my GUI didn't show up that time I applied this?

Comment: @MegaManX I did not understand what you are trying to say, can you be more specific?

Comment: Sorry leeduhem, I appreciated your help. I just don't understand what happen when I applied this. I am using perl tk too, meaning I am using gui and when I tried this, nothing loaded. I'll double check maybe I did something wrong.. Thanks alot again! :)

Comment: will sleep(300) be an optimization?

Comment: @Wordzilla I believe Perl compiler can figure out that `5 * 60` equals `300` and replaces it with `300` directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want non-blocking timer, look for one of this modules:

https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Prima/pod/Prima/Timer.pod
https://metacpan.org/pod/EV